ServiceBusError: InvalidOperationError: Cannot create a message browser
Please help with the below issue:
ServiceBusError:
InvalidOperationError: Cannot create a message browser on an entity with auto-forwarding enabled. Reference:26xxxx0b, TrackingId:baxxxxxB12, SystemTracker:spxxxxod:Topic:vexxxxic|asr, Timestamp:2024-06-14T06:11:02 Reference:cexxxxxxcb, TrackingId:48

all suggestions are welcome!
I tried fetching the messages from servicebus using "Peek from start" tab but getting the error. I expect the messages to be fetched and shown

Can you share more details on your exact issue. @Rohan Nandurkar

After enabling auto forwarding feature in a service bus, message peeking might not be supported from the portal by default. But the message forwarding operation will occur successfully in a destination queue or topic.
Also,

Service Bus doesn't allow creating a message receiver on a source entity with auto forwarding enabled.

Refer MSDoc for the above relevant information.
So, if you want to peek the messages, you need to disable auto forwarding feature and try it.
I have also tried the similar approach in my environment and received the same alert as shown below.

As a workaround, try enabling autoforward feature using CLI and try peek from start messages from the Portal to avoid conflicts.
 az servicebus queue create --resource-group "asha" --namespace-name "newsbjh" --name myqueue --forward-to latestqueue



Refer MSDoc to browse and peek messages in a service bus using Python or C#.
If still the issue persists, Check if there are any other features that are blocking the peek operation in both source and destination queues or topics.
